# Same type ascription loses type member information on variable declaration but not on method parameter declaration

Tags: scala, path-dependent-type, type-members

Consider path-dependent type

```
trait Foo[In] {
  type Out
  def f(v: In): Out
}

implicit val preciseFooInt: Foo[Int] { type Out = String } = new Foo[Int] {
  type Out = String
  def f(v: Int): String = v.toString
}
```

where we see output type `Out` declared as type member. Also note the precisely declared type of `preciseFooInt` instance

```
Foo[Int] { type Out = String }
```

Now let's lose the type member precision by forcing assignment to its supertype

```
val ev: Foo[Int] = preciseFooInt
```

Because we omitted type refinement `{ type Out = String }` the compiler does not know the output type is precisely `String` which makes sense

```
scala> val ev: Foo[Int] = preciseFooInt
val ev: Foo[Int] = $anon$1@2fd641f6

scala> val s: String = ev.f(42)
                           ^
       error: type mismatch;
        found   : ev.Out
        required: String
```

However let's do very similar motions but via method parameter declaration

```
def g(ev: Foo[Int]) = ev.f(42)
```

Note how method parameter `ev` has exactly the same type ascription as variable `ev` before, namely `Foo[Int]` without the specific type member refinement `{ type Out = String }`. Nevertheless now there is no loss of type member precision

```
scala> def g(ev: Foo[Int]) = ev.f(42)
def g(ev: Foo[Int]): ev.Out

scala> val s: String = g(ev = preciseFooInt)
val s: String = 42
```

What is the difference between the variable declaration and method parameter declaration with respect to type members? Given type ascription was the same in both cases, why was there no loss of information in method parameter case?

Comment: 1. *"why was there no loss of information in method parameter case?"* - "Why? - Because we can." 2. Why was there loss of information in variable declaration case? - because there is no return type to infer, and no place to store the inferable `ev.Out` type. Where would you expect it to put the `ev.Out` in the case of variable declaration?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Ah I see, if return type is removed out of the equation then indeed it behaves the [same](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/pjIJm0KDT52ep7Ofr0eZbg).

Comment: With the method, you basically have a dependent type. The return type of the method is not `String` but `ev.Out`, which is `String` for `preciseFooInt`.