# How to help the Scala 3 compiler infer a path-dependent-type?

Tags: scala, type-inference, scala-3, path-dependent-type

Suppose that, whenever type `A` can represent a less-than-perfectly-precise measurement of a physical value, I'll have an instance of `Imprecise[A]`.

```scala
trait Imprecise[A]:
  type Precision
  val ord: Ordering[Precision]
  def precision(a: A): Precision
```

For example, this `Bounds` type has a given instance in its companion object:

```scala
case class Bounds[N: Numeric](min: N, max: N):
  if summon[Ordering[N]].compare(min, max) > 1 then
    throw new IllegalArgumentException

object Bounds:
  import scala.math.Numeric.Implicits.infixNumericOps
  import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits.infixOrderingOps
  given [N: Numeric]: Imprecise[Bounds[N]] with
    type Precision = N
    val ord = summon[Ordering[N]]
    def precision(rng: Bounds[N]) = rng.max - rng.min
```

Now my program can start dealing with the physical features that need to be observed:

```scala
trait Feature[A:  Imprecise]:
  type Observation = A
  val imprecise = summon[Imprecise[A]]
  type Precision = imprecise.Precision

  def within(bound: Precision) = new RequiredFeature(this, bound)

class RequiredFeature(val feature: Feature[_], val min_precision: feature.Precision)


case class Temperature(chamber_id: Int) extends Feature[Bounds[Double]]
case class Pressure(chamber_id: Int) extends Feature[Bounds[Float]]
```

But when, at last, I try to make a required feature:

```scala
val rf = Temperature(3).within(7.0)
```

the compiler complains

```
Found:    (7.0d : Double)
Required: ?1.Precision

where:    ?1 is an unknown value of type exp.Temperature

val rf = Temperature(3).within(7.0)
```

The code written so far can be made to compile if I forego any path-dependent types and pass the precision around everywhere as a regular generic type parameter.  But what if I don't want to do that?  Is there some strategy like the Aux pattern that will help the compiler see that this is a valid call to `within`?

Comment: Shoud `summon[Ordering[N]].compare(min, max) > 1` be `= 1`? (or `> 0`?)

Comment: `class RequiredFeature` doesn't have generic but you use it in `def within(bound: Precision) = new RequiredFeature[A](this, bound)` as if it had.

Comment: @DmytroMitin that's probably me tweaking my code wrong as I copy it into Stackoverflow.  I'll edit it to make sure the only error is the one I'm asking about.

Comment: @DmytroMitin I think [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/opGbTJPWS6ax31eqVDD4vw/22) shows the root of the problem, for some reason the compiler doesn't know the correct type of Precision not sure if this is desired, or a bug, or an error in the code.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Yes `compare(min, max) > 1` should be `compare(min, max) > 0`, but that has no bearing on the type inference here.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez  indeed your scastie link demonstrates perfectly the problem I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

This question is similar to [Cannot prove equivalence with a path dependent type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69120836/cannot-prove-equivalence-with-a-path-dependent-type)

The thing is not in implicits, the thing is in path-dependent types. The simplest example is

```
trait A:
  type T

val a0 = new A:
  type T = Int

summon[a0.T =:= Int]

class B(val a: A) // a has type A, not A { type T = ... }

val b = B(a0)

// summon[b.a.T =:= Int] // doesn't compile
```

To make this compile we could use singleton types `class B(val a: a0.type)` or add a type parameter `class B[_T](val a: A { type T = _T })`.

`trait Feature[A:  Imprecise]` is desugared into `trait Feature[A](using ev: Imprecise[A])` and here you're loosing type refinement, upcasting `Imprecise[A] { type Precision = ... }` to just `Imprecise[A]`. Difference in behavior of path-dependent types in variable vs. method parameter is discussed in [Same type ascription loses type member information on variable declaration but not on method parameter declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67167812/same-type-ascription-loses-type-member-information-on-variable-declaration-but-n) and `using ev: Imprecise[A]` in `trait Feature[A](using ev: Imprecise[A])` declares a variable.

So you should restore type refinement of `Imprecise` and add a type parameter to `Feature`

```
trait Imprecise[A]:
  type Precision
  val ord: Ordering[Precision]
  def precision(a: A): Precision

object Imprecise:
  type Aux[A, P] = Imprecise[A] with
    type Precision = P

case class Bounds[N: Numeric](min: N, max: N):
  if summon[Ordering[N]].compare(min, max) > 0 then
    throw new IllegalArgumentException

object Bounds:
  import Numeric.Implicits._
  given [N: Numeric]: Imprecise[Bounds[N]] with
    type Precision = N
    val ord = summon[Ordering[N]]
    def precision(rng: Bounds[N]) = rng.max - rng.min

trait Feature[A, P](using Imprecise.Aux[A, P]):
  type Observation = A
  val imprecise = summon[Imprecise[A]]
  type Precision = imprecise.Precision

  def within(bound: Precision) = new RequiredFeature(this, bound)

class RequiredFeature(val feature: Feature[_,_], val min_precision: feature.Precision)

case class Temperature(chamber_id: Int) extends Feature[Bounds[Double], Double]
case class Pressure(chamber_id: Int) extends Feature[Bounds[Float], Float]

val rf = Temperature(3).within(7.0)
```

or add a type member to `Feature`

```
trait Imprecise[A]:
  type Precision
  val ord: Ordering[Precision]
  def precision(a: A): Precision

object Imprecise:
  type Aux[A, P] = Imprecise[A] with
    type Precision = P

case class Bounds[N: Numeric](min: N, max: N):
  if summon[Ordering[N]].compare(min, max) > 0 then
    throw new IllegalArgumentException

object Bounds:
  import Numeric.Implicits._
  given [N: Numeric]: Imprecise[Bounds[N]] with
    type Precision = N
    val ord = summon[Ordering[N]]
    def precision(rng: Bounds[N]) = rng.max - rng.min

trait Feature[A]:
  type P
  val ev: Imprecise.Aux[A, P]
  given Imprecise.Aux[A, P] = ev

  type Observation = A
  val imprecise = summon[Imprecise[A]] // ev
  type Precision = imprecise.Precision // P

  def within(bound: Precision) = new RequiredFeature(this, bound)

class RequiredFeature(val feature: Feature[_], val min_precision: feature.Precision)

case class Temperature[_P](chamber_id: Int)(using _ev: Imprecise.Aux[Bounds[Double], _P]) extends Feature[Bounds[Double]]:
  type P = _P
  val ev = _ev
case class Pressure[_P](chamber_id: Int)(using _ev: Imprecise.Aux[Bounds[Float], _P]) extends Feature[Bounds[Float]]:
  type P = _P
  val ev = _ev

val rf = Temperature(3).within(7.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @DmytroMitin excellent answer, here is a step by step analysis for those with slow minds like mine :)

The explanation is based on this example code:

```scala
    class Outer {
        class Inner
        def doSomething(a: Inner): Unit = ()
    }

    val outerRef = new Outer
```

The first thing we have to note is that the type of the reference `outerRef` is not `Outer` but `outerRef.type`, which is assignable to `Outer` but not the opposite. That happens even if the type of `outerRef` were specified explicitly to be `Outer` (`val outerRef: Outer = new Outer`).

```scala
    summon[outerRef.type <:< Outer]
```

The second thing we have to note is that a copy of a reference does not have the same type than the original reference.

```scala
    val copyOfOuterRef = outerRef
```

Here the type of the reference `copyOfOuterRef` is not `outerRef.type` but `copyOfOuterRef.type`, which is assignable to `Outer` but not to `outerRef.type`.

```scala
    summon[copyOfOuterRef.type <:< Outer] // compiles
    
    summon[copyOfOuterRef.type =:= outerRef.type] // does not compile
    summon[copyOfOuterRef.type <:< outerRef.type] // does not compile
    summon[outerRef.type <:< copyOfOuterRef.type] // does not compile
```

**What does all this have to do with path-dependent-types?**

The path-dependent-type assignability rules is based on the singleton type of the references involved in the path.

The following line defines a reference whose type is assignable to the path-dependent-type `outerRef.Inner`.

```scala
    val innerRef = new outerRef.Inner
```

Therefore, it is suitable to be the argument of the `outerRef.doSomething` method.

```scala
    outerRef.doSomething(innerRef) // compiles
    summon[innerRef.type <:< outerRef.Inner] // compiles
```

But not suitable to be the argument of the `copyOfOuterRef.doSomething` method.

```scala
    copyOfOuterRef.doSomething(innerRef) // does not compile
    summon[innerRef.type <:< copyOfOuterRef.Inner]  // does not compile
```

because the singleton type of the references involved in the paths is not the same.

```scala
summon[copyOfOuterRef.type =:= outerRef.type] // does not compile
```

To solve that, we have to make the copy of the reference have the same singleton-type than the original reference.

```scala
    val copyOfOuterRefWithSameType: outerRef.type = outerRef
```

Now the singleton type of the references that conform both paths, `outerRef.X` and `copyOfOuterRefWithSameType.X`, are the same. Therefore

```scala
    copyOfOuterRefWithSameType.doSomething(innerRef) // compiles
    summon[outerRef.type =:= copyOfOuterRefWithSameType.type] // compiles
    summon[outerRef.Inner =:= copyOfOuterRefWithSameType.Inner] // compiles
```

**A more realistic case**

Usually, we can't change the type of the second reference (the copy of the first) because the first reference is out of the scope. For example, when the second reference (the copy) is a member a previously defined class.

```
    class User(val outer: Outer) // defined in some place where the `outerRef` reference is not accesible.
```

```scala
    val outerRef = new Outer
    val user = new User(outerRef)
```

Here both `user.outer` and `outerRef` reference the same instance of `Outer` but because the path-dependent-type is based on the singleton type of the references involved, the assignability fails.

```scala
    val outerRef = new Outer
    val innerRef = new outerRef.Inner

    user.outer.doSomething(innerRef) // does not compile
    summon[innerRef.type <:< user.outer.Inner] // does not compile
```

because

```scala
    summon[user.outer.Inner =:= outerRef.Inner] // does not compile
```

To solve that we have to make the singleton type of the `outer` member be equivalent to the type of `outerRef`, which is the singleton type `outerRef.type`. We can achieve that parameterizing the member type.

```scala
    class UserBis[O <: Outer](val outer: O)

    val outerRef = new Outer
    val innerRef = new outerRef.Inner
    val userBis = new UserBis[outerRef.type](outerRef)
    
    userBis.outer.doSomething(innerRef) // compiles
    summon[userBis.outer.type =:= outerRef.type] // compiles
    summon[userBis.outer.Inner =:= outerRef.Inner] // compiles
```